# Can the values stored in an object of a class be replaced after creation of the object in Java?

Tags: java, networking

Suppose I have a scenario where I have 2 machines: `Client A` & `Client B`. Now if I create an object in a class of Client A machine suppose `xyz obja=new xyz(4,6)` and this object ‘obja' I transferred to Client B.

In the Client B machine the values of obja are read and processed upon, after processing(assuming some or other math function) the class of Client B creates its own object suppose `abc objb=new abc(10,1)` and this object is transferred to Client A again.

Now is it possible to read the values in `objb` and replace these values with the existing values in `obja` itself.

**Basically my question is whether or not existing values in an object can be replaced with other values?**

P.S.: All of the matter above is regarding to **Java** & I am not trying to implement the above given example, I only want to clear this concept and hence I'm not including any code. The above example is only created for as to better understand the question.

Comment: Getters and setters?

Comment: Can existing values in an object can be replaced with other values? Sure, write some member functions.

Comment: Yes, the values of variables can be modified.  Did you try anything?  Has some attempt not worked as expected?

Comment: @David actually I've tried objectname.accept() but I'm not sure which method to use to replace values in the object.

Comment: @Bathsheba could they directly replace the contents of one object with another or I'd have to accept values from one object store them in a variables and then copy the contents of those variable into the other object?

Comment: @AnkitPanchal: Well, what does that `accept()` method *do*?  What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?  Can you demonstrate with a small code example?

Comment: Also, have a look at "java rmi".

Comment: @David Nevermind I got it all sorted via Peter Lawrey's method. Thanks for your time anyways. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks I'll give that a go too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you serialize an object you send a copy of that data across the network.  When you read that copy, you won't see the changes made to the original.

What you can do however, is send another copy of that object on each significant update.  This way, any downstream client which needs to see the latest version can do so by replacing the old copy with the new one each time.

Comment: You mean to replace the entire object with the original one whenever there's a significant update?

Comment: @AnkitPanchal That is the simplest approach. Another is to send a message which can apply the same changes to the object.  This is useful when the information about the change is small compared to the data it alters.

Comment: Thanks man. Your method definitely seems the most feasible to me. Cheers. :)